# Laravel 5 - Timezone Hora Errada

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Troquei a timezone `'timezone' => 'America/Sao_Paulo'`, mas não está pegando o `GMT +3`, que é o de Brasília.

Tem que trocar alguma outra coisa em algum outro lugar, fora app.php?

Comment: Que horas está pegando? America/Sao_Paulo é -3.

Comment: Como está na config do PHP ?

Comment: vc pode criar uma controller de teste com o código `echo date_default_timezone_get();` e `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');` para modificar o timezone e conferir se a mudanção acontece.

Comment: Sua pergunta tem neste momento dois votos para o fechamento, um como problema que não pode ser reproduzido ou erro de digitação e um como não sendo clara o bastante. Lendo a sua pergunta, entendo que falta contexto e detalhamento sobre o seu problema e sobre o que você fez ou não fez no código. Quanto a votação para fechar ou não, eu particularmente me abstenho.